# Need an equation in excel that finds the exact match not the first match from a list

Tags: excel

I'm using the following formula to search in  a column of cells based on a list:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(PRODUCT_TALL[Product],MATCH(TRUE,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(PRODUCT_TALL[Product],K36,1))),0),1),"")
```

But it returns the first match. For example:

**List contains**

```
Ator
Atoreza
Atorvastatin
```

What is returned

[image]

But what should be added is Atorvastatin because it is the exact match.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do an index & match, then you are going about it the wrong way. Try this:

=IFERROR(INDEX(PRODUCT_TALL[Product],MATCH(K36,PRODUCT_TALL[Product],0),1),"")

In 'MATCH(K36,PRODUCT_TALL[Product],0),1)' I assumed K36 was the value you wanted to lookup for an exact match and that it could be found in the first column of your array.